# Clear Form Fields on Inactivity

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm currently working on a simple form that stores users inputted information to a database.

The form will be displayed on iPads at a Kiosk.

If a user walks up to the form and starts to fill in the fields, but doesn't finish and walks away, I want the form fields to clear for the next person.

This is being done to prevent someone from walking up to an iPad with half of the previous users information that was never submitted.

I know I'll have to use Javascript, but I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say handle the `keydown` event of the `window` object and save the current time. Something like this:

```
var timerID = null;
var timeoutDuration = 60000; // Put the timeout duration here

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(timerID !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        timerID = null;
    }

    timerID = setTimeout(function() {
        // Clear all the fields here
    }, timeoutDuration);
}, false);
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/BnpSH/)

Comment: I would reload the page - simpler solution and less prone to error in the event of the page getting modified.

Comment: @EdHeal: I was going to do that, but I remembered some browsers preserve what was entered on refresh. I don't know if iDevices do that because I don't have one to try it on.

Comment: I assumed that it is at a kisok that the person could prevent this.

Comment: @EdHeal: It says "iPads at a kiosk". You can't really customize iPads.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reload the page after a period of inactivity? Safer bet. Just use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` JavaScript functions to achieve this when the fields get updated to reset the timers. Use `setTimeout` to reload the page. This will ensure that the page is reset.

See [Reload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) and [JavaScript timing](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best thing to use it the javaScript timing event.

This can be done by `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` functions.  Then in those functions you can address the input boxes `document.getElementById("nameofElement")` and then clear them.

Good example that is easy to follow see : 
[JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Hope this helps.